# Wordpress admin page cant be found/accessed

Tags: wordpress, backend, wordpress-admin

FYI: I am able to access the c-panel

Admin page displays the following:

[image]

Front end seems to be displaying properly:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

this is because your admin dashboard ulr is redirected (maybe by a plugin, server setting, .htaccess...).

You can access wp dashboard login by **[this url](https://therealtruth.in/wp-login.php)** - Basically, just add **"/wp-login.php"** follow you site URL.

Comment: Thank you so much. Will check all the points mentioned by you.